# How to include "Empty" constant in class

Tags: c#, .net, class, constants, member

I have a class and I would like to include an "Empty" constant member similar to Point.Empty in System.Drawing. Is that possible?

Here's a simplified version of what is giving an error:

```
public class TrivialClass
{
    public const TrivialClass Empty = new TrivialClass(0);
    public int MyValue;
    public TrivialClass(int InitialValue)
    {
        MyValue = InitialValue;
    }
}
```

The error given is: *TrivialClass.Empty is of type TrivialClass. A const field of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null.*

If it matters, I'd like to use it like this:

```
void SomeFunction()
{
    TrivialClass myTrivial = TrivialClass.Empty;
    // Do stuff ...
}
```

Comment: `yes I know this is .NET and there is no Main` Think again....

Comment: @I4V thank you for the insight. Interesting and I'll look into that later but I fail to see how that helps with the question.

Comment: @AppFzx: He's just saying that .NET *does* use a static `Main` method as the default entry point.

Comment: @mellamokb Thanks. I changed it since it was a confusing name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `static readonly` for these types. Constants can only be initialised with literal values (e.g. numbers, strings).

```
public class TrivialClass
{
    public static readonly TrivialClass Empty = new TrivialClass(0);
    public int MyValue;
    public TrivialClass(int InitialValue)
    {
        MyValue = InitialValue;
    }
}
```

After looking up the definition. `Point.Empty` is also `static readonly`. [Reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.empty.aspx).

Comment: Whether or not `const` can be used has nothing to do with whether it's a reference type or a value type.  You can only assign a compile time constant to such an identifier.  For any reference value that is a compile time literal (i.e. `null` or any string literals) those can work.  For value types, they still need to be compile time literals (meaning pretty much just numeric types).  `default(...)` is not a compile time literal.

Comment: @flem I already mentioned string as a reference type, and `char` is a value type, not a reference type, but yes, there are compile time literals for characters.

Comment: Oh, and `Point` is not a reference type, it's a value type.

Comment: @Servy. Typo on my part. That paragraph may make more sense with that correction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick shoot, but I would suggest that Point.Empty is a static member, not a constant:

```
public class TrivialClass
{
    public static readonly TrivialClass Empty = new TrivialClass(0);
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're right, `Point.Empty` is static. It's also readonly. See my answer.